# Calling SOAP client(suds) in python returning error AuthenticationError.LOGIN_COOKIE_REQUIRED

Tags: python, api, soap, suds

I am 1 week old in python.
I am calling suds soap api from python .
Here is my code.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
if __debug__:
    logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
client = Client(wsdlurl, soapheaders='string')
# Create ClientCustomerId parameter value for mutate method
clientId = client.factory.create("ClientCustomerId")
product = client.factory.create("Product")
clientId.product = product.INVITE_ADVERTISER
clientId.entityId = XXXX

# Create UserListOperation parameter value for mutate method
# Create UserList Object
userList = client.factory.create("UserList")
millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
userList.name = "Demographic segment # %s" % millis
userList.description = "Target dempographic description"
userList.integrationCode = "XXX"
d = timedelta(days=365)
userList.membershipLifeSpan = d.days
userListOperation = client.factory.create("UserListOperation")
userListOperation.operand = userList
operator = client.factory.create("Operator")
userListOperation.operator = operator.ADD
print userListOperation
operations = [userListOperation]
result = client.service.mutate(clientId, userListOperation)  //Error raises here
print result
```

While calling the mutate() method getting error like Server raised fault: '[AuthenticationError.LOGIN_COOKIE_REQUIRED @ ; trigger:'']'

To the Client method i added soapheaders like client = Client(wsdlurl,soapheaders='string'),otherwise i am getting error 'Missing soap header'

As it is login cookie error tried passing access token but nothing worked.
    client = Client(wsdlurl,headers{'key':'value'},soapheaders='string')#,soapheaders{'userAgent':'administrator'})

```
#atoken = Element('token').setText(token)
#locale = Element('locale').setText('en')
#client.set_options(soapheaders=(atoken,locale))
```

Browsed a lot but nothing seems to be useful.
Any help??

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution,may be useful to any starters.

While calling SOAP API using suds module we need to set the headers,in my case i am passing the access token from OAuth authentication,like this

```
code='Bearer %s'%accToken
headers={'Authorization':code}
client = Client(wsdlurl,headers=headers,soapheaders=(appname))
```

Here accToken is my access token,headers is a dictionary where i am passing  key is 'Authorization' and Value is 'Bearer XXX(accToken)',appname is my application name(just a string)

Cheers